# Pronunciation of the combination "st" in Spanish accents

Tags: españa, pronunciación, dialectos, fonología

I have noticed some people from Andalusia pronouncing the combination "st" in reverse in a word, as "ch" (for example "donde está" will sound like "donde echá"). Is it a particularity of the local accent of some kind of slang? In what areas, if any, can this pronunciation be heard?

Comment: What you're hearing is actually [ts], which is phonetically very close to "ch" [tʃ]. I remember being puzzled by this same sound when I spent a few days in Andalusia.

Comment: Related question: [Is there a rule for s-aspiration?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/5557/is-there-a-certain-rule-for-s-aspiration).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This affrication of `/st/` is indeed particular to Western Andalusian:

> An affricated dentoalveolar stop [t<sup>s</sup>] (*listo* [ˈlit<sup>s</sup>o]) has been described as a variant of /st/-clusters. This sound is perceptually and acoustically similar to [t<sup>h</sup>], another /st/-allophone in Seville Spanish.
>
> - [*Affrication of /st/-clusters in Western Andalusian Spanish: variation and change from a sociophonetic point of view*](http://edizioni.sns.it/en/downloadable/download/sample/sample_id/17/), Hanna Ruch (2010)

The study reports that it more often occurs in younger, educated speakers, and in informal speech:

> The frequency of occurrence of [t<sup>s</sup>] was negatively correlated with
> age and speech formality level, and positively correlated with the level of education. The social distribution of [t<sup>s</sup>] suggests a sound change in progress in Seville Spanish.

The study posits the novel sound change: [ht] ⟶ [t<sup>h</sup>] ⟶ [t<sup>s</sup>] (noting that this affricate has not been described in the traditional dialectological studies).

Also note the distinction between Eastern and Western realization of /s/ aspiration when it occurs before consonants (pre- and post- respectively):

> In Eastern Andalusian Spanish, /sp, st, sk/ clusters are usually realized with preaspiration [hp, ht, hk], whereas in Western Andalusian Spanish, postaspiration [p<sup>h</sup>, t<sup>h</sup>, k<sup>h</sup>] is much more frequent, at
> least among younger speakers...